# empty css while using @import in a css link

Tags: css, jsf-2

My css files are loaded empty 
I checked in firebug my css file all.css it is recognized and a.css,b.css,c.css are also recognized but the problem that they are empty

all.css

```
@import url(a.css)  
@import url(b.css)  
@import url(c.css)
```

In JSF page i am adding all.css

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="all.css" />
```

So how can i add the 3 css without adding them explicitly i want to combine them in one css file

Comment: Might want to have a look at this:

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler;jsessionid=nlGOQOjJmihdBZL41BQQs+Z5

Comment: Have you tried `code`@import url("#{resource['css/font-awesome.css']}");`code` ?

Comment: Probably a path problem as @JonathasPacífico stated, could be easily tested with Firebug

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and I solved it as below. May be it helps other people who read this later:

Directory structure:

```
-WebContent
 -WEB-INF
  -resources
   -css
     a.css
     b.css
```

**b.css:**

```
body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

**a.css**

```
@IMPORT url("#{resource['css:b.css']}");

div { ... }
a   { ... }
```

**:** is important. If *b.css* file was in another folder, *default* i.e., in the *css* folder, ***@IMPORT url*** would be like this:

```
@IMPORT url("#{resource['css:default/b.css']}");
```

Left side of the colon is the library name and the right of the colon is the path for the imported css file.

Comment: The `:` is not important. You misunderstood meaning of "library". Just use `/` the usual way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Answer (score 0):

I think to use @import correctly it must be the absolute first thing in your style sheet. Like not even comments can come before the declarations.

Try making a stylesheet which does nothing but calls the @imports.

Also when in doubt, make a JS fiddle for us to look at.